# CSS - Transition between backgrounds

Tags: css, angular, css-transitions, gradient

I want to have a transition when I change background on click. The original background is a gradient while the second background is a shade of blue applied to the first background. Like so:

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

I can't find a way to apply a simple 0.3s transition for this change.

My styles:

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(25deg, #b24592, #f15f79) no-repeat;
}

.layer {
    background: rgba(9, 21, 110, 0.37);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

My .html:

```
<body>
    <div class="layer" [hidden]="shopIsOpen">
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

What can I do to implement a simple transition between these two backgrounds on a click event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not transition gradients.  Try transitioning the opacity or height of .layer instead

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `transition` doesn't work with `linear-gradient`, instead you have to work with `opacity` or with moving `background-position` on hover.

```css
.magic {
  background: linear-gradient(25deg, #b24592, #f15f79);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.magic::after {
  background: linear-gradient(25deg, #f15f79, #b24592);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.magic:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="magic"></div>
```

Comment: would this work for a click event instead of hover?

Comment: yes, change css selector `.magic:hover::after` on '.magic.clicked::after` and on click by JS add class `clicked` to your background element (in our case it's `.magic`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not changing the colors or position of colors in linear-gradient you can just add a opacity property to the overlay element ".layer" and add hover  event to it

And if you are trying to change the color or their position you can add an animation of gradient with tools like gradient-animator (which does it by changing the background postion as you can't add transition or animation to css gradient) and append it to the body directly with js

Comment: How would it work for a click event instead of hover?

Comment: Yes if you are using js you can do it